# GSAP/CSS transform origin and glitchy hover effect/ SVG Regions

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, transform, gsap

I am attempting to animate an svg doughnut circle with gsap. After much testing with code and layering, I am stumped with a glitchy hover effect (which I tried to resolve with pointer events) and the transform origin is only applied to a few of the expanded tabs. I am wondering if this might be that the tabs may have a different bounding box?

Comments added per request:

Side Note: I've tried applying fill-box to entire svg instead, I'm wondering if I need a parent layer thats an exact square so I can apply the transform origin for the child "expandtabs" to the center of that?

I assumed I needed to iterate through an array of both to have the tabs correspond. Unless the tabs were children of each other?

TLDR; Tabs are not scaling from center of circle, and glitchy hover effect

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/jpark197/pen/vYWYzXL)

```
.expandtab {
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: fill-box;
    transform-origin: -15px 25%;
}
```

Javascript:

```
const subTabs = gsap.utils.toArray(".subtab");
const expandTabs = gsap.utils.toArray(".expandtab");
const tl = gsap.timeline({ defaults: { duration: .05, } });

tl.set(expandTabs, {
    visibility: "hidden",
    opacity: 0,
    scale: 0,
});

subTabs.forEach((subTab, index) => {
    let expandTab = expandTabs[index];

    // Event Listener Hover on
    subTabs[index].addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
        console.log("you clicked region number " + index);
        tl.to(expandTab, {
            visibility: "visible",
            opacity: 1,
            scale: 1,
        });
    });

    // Event Listener Hover off
    subTabs[index].addEventListener("mouseout", (event) => {
        console.log("you exited region number " + index);
        tl.to(expandTab, {
            opacity: 0,
            scale: 0,
            visibility: "hidden",
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Side Note: I've tried applying fill-box to entire svg instead, I'm wondering if I need a parent layer thats an exact square so I can apply the transform origin for the child "expandtabs" to the center of that?

Comment: OK... that is just a region in a svg...

Comment: I assumed I needed to iterate through an array of both to have the tabs correspond. Unless the tabs were children of each other?

Comment: I am not the designer of the svg, I imagine this is something to be resolved in illustrator...

Comment: Can you edit your question with those comments you just made... And specify you are handling regions of a SVG. Making a working snippet would help.

Comment: I put the code pen because svg code is bloated, I'll add a snippet though

Comment: Ok, I see now. Try just replacing the events with `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, for fun.

Comment: Nice, this does seem to solve the glitchy hover issue. I wonder why that is?

Comment: Still having an issue with the origin point for the scale, we want the tabs to scale from the center point of the inner circle edge, as if they are "expanding out" from the border of the inner circle

Comment: About the transform origin, you will have to add an additional class to eack part... And specify a direction specific to each of them.

Comment: I'm assuming I could accomplish that with nth-child pseudo selectors? Also do you mean I would need to specify a transform origin specific to each individual tab? Thank you also!

Comment: Yes... I am trying on my side... And I'm starting to think you should scale fro 0.5 (or something close to the "real" size to scale 1. -- And then, you will need a translation in the right direction. -- Now I think that transform-origin is not the solution... Or at least not the complete one. It may be just a part of it.

Comment: Thank you... I just tried the 0.5 scale and it does look MUCH better for some of the tabs, still not consistent all around, I think you are right on the direction but I'm unsure where to begin with that. I'll play around with it as well

Comment: I would try `tl.to(expandTab, {scale: 1, opacity: 1, x: 20px, y: 20px}` *(px values are just as example)* where x and y will be different for each. You can use the `index` to decide it.

Comment: There is a method called `.fromTo` to specify a start point and a destination point ;) That probably is the tool you need. -- Look [here](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/gsap.fromTo())

Comment: Thank you!! I'll mess around with this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241412/discussion-between-jpark197-and-louys-patrice-bessette).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the glitchy hover effect, the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` will do the job better. `mouseover` is firering way to much...

For the "growing" effect, it is more complex. The `transform-origin` CSS property won't be enought. Any way, you will need different values for each five parts of the circle.

Additionnaly, you will need to adjust a transition to "fit" or "keep" the inner part of the circle in place. I suggest you to look at the [fromTo](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/gsap.fromTo()) method of GSAP. That will allow you to specify explicitely the starting and the landing coordinates.

Be patient! ;)